# Makefile error while compiling LwbT using TI Microcontroller IDE

Tags: microcontroller, embedded, bluetooth

I am trying to port Lwbt to TI MSP430 Microcontroller. As a first step, I am compiling the lwbt in TI Code Composer studio as a Standard C Make Project. I have downloaded the lwbt code from https://github.com/lwalkera/lwBT. I have set the path for build directory and build commands. I have also downloaded Mingw. GCC works fine which I checked by typing `gcc` in the command prompt. But while building the project, I get the below error.

```
gmake -f Makefile all 
process_begin: CreateProcess(NULL, cat filelist, ...) failed.
process_begin: CreateProcess(NULL, cat filelist, ...) failed.
--[OUT]-- 
gcc: no input files
gmake: *** [lwbt.out] Error 1
```

I have been struggling with this error for last 1 week. Desperate for help.

Thanks

Answer (score 2):

In order to port to MSP430, you'll need to modify the makefile to point to the CCS compiler. You'll need to provide the right command line options. You'll also need to hook in your hardware through whatever HAL layers the library provides.

As the project already assumes GCC, you might find porting easier using msp430-gcc.

It sounds as though you are trying to compile lwBT for your PC using MingW and failing. Does your C compiler actually work? Try compiling a "hello world" program.

Look at the Makefile, what commands is it actually running? Remove any '@' characters before lines that execute commands, so you can see what's going on under the hood.

Comment: Hello Joby Taffey,

Thanks for your response. I had couple of problems. First the version of make (3.8.1) had a bug . So i installed make 3.8.2 version. The next problem was the lwbt makefile had linux commands (cat/shell) which the mingw compiler didnt recognise. So I altered the makefile and finally it is running. Of course, it will never be a dream run, there are other compiler errors not related to make or mingw which I hope to solve soon :):). Many thanks for taking the time out.

Comment: If the makefile relies on cat and sh, porting will be easier from within cygwin - or ideally, Linux